# OpenCV Webcam not showing till it captures and image

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I have been trying to make a camera webapp using Flask and OpenCV. The snippet here generates frame by frame in the camera so I can use it as a video feed for my page:

```
def gen_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read() 
        if success:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cv2.flip(frame,1))
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
```

I have a `capture()` function that captures an image after a specified time. But when I add the function at the end like this:

```
def gen_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read() 
        if success:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cv2.flip(frame,1))
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
                   
            capture()
```

the webcam doesn't show and just shows a static image after it captures it. I want it to be able to be moving till it captures and image and then shows the static image.

Answer (score 0):

If your response is of type "multipart/x-mixed-replace" it is expecting multiple frames. It is not very efficient but one solution is to keep sending the same frame over and over. Like:

```
static_frame = None
def gen_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read() 
        if success:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cv2.flip(frame,1))
            if not static_frame:
                frame = buffer.tobytes()
            else:
                frame = static_frame
            if random_event():
                static_frame = frame
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
```

Comment: Hi! yes i'm using a response 'multipart/x-mixed-replace' tried to use your solution and to no avail. It still shows the static image that it has captured and saved. though im still thinking of another way with your solution as a lead.